# Customize Generic Error Message for Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I'm trying to customize the generic error message in Dynamics 365 (e.g: an error when a user doesn't have enough privilege like 'you do not have enough privileges...'). Which configuration I need to update to achieve it?

Comment: As far as I know these Generic Out of Box Error messages cannot be modified. Reason been Dynamics did not gave any access to control these triggers. What you could do is on particular Trigger for example create update and so on, create your own plugin which will check your access and then display message

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Settings -> Customizations -> Customize the System -> Entities -> User -> Messages`

You should be able to configure particular text in here:

[image]

Alternatively, you can export the translations & update in bulk, then re-import it.

[image]