# Bulk Update of Entity Messages in Microsoft Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

**My Requirement**

I have renamed my **CASE** entity display name to **ENQUIRY** so wanted to Change all CASE entity messages(e.g. Wherever "CASE" is used in message, will be changed to "ENQUIRY").

I tried getting the **ResourceKey** name from all the **REGX** file from the CRM, since was not sure which REGX file will be having the required ResourceKey, still was not getting any result.

When I added the entity messages for "CASE" entity and exported the solution the **customization.xml** had the following ResourceKeys and many more

[image: Customization.xml]

So wanted to know how can we perform an bulk Update on Entity Messages without manually going and changing each message for an entity in Microsoft Dynamics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are not trying to change schema name references or this ResourceKey, and you are trying [these generic Entity messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57596011/7920473). You can export translations to bulk edit in Excel and reimport. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/modify-messages-entity#edit-messages-by-exporting-editing-and-importing-translations)

[image]

They are stored in `displaystrings` entity. If you want to try programmatically - still web api has possibility with below endpoint. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/displaystring?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)

```
[organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/displaystrings
```

The plural name (display name) should be used in a parameterized way from the CRM product perspective, though I remember the system views (Active cases, etc) were needed to be taken care after such display name changes. The `customizations.xml` will have them to update in one shot.